# TYPO3 gridelement via typoscript

Tags: typoscript, typo3-8.x, tx-gridelements

I use TYPO3 8.7. I want to include contact form on site via typoscript. This contact form inserted in gridelement with id=29. 
In typoscript I write

```
lib.contactForm = RECORDS
lib.contactForm {
  source = 29
  tables = tt_content
  dontChekPid = 1
}
```

When I logged into back-end I see the form. When I logout from back-end I don't see my form.

Answer (score 0):

For TYPO3 8 it is necessary to include Page TSConfig for gridelements in backend on root page.

Comment: You can include the PageTSconfig wherever and however you like. You just have to make sure that the source you are using is available with pure frontend rendering too. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure the source you are using to include your Gridelements configurations is available with pure frontend rendering.

While this is easy for record based CE backend layouts, it might be a problem with file based configurations. Make sure you include file based configurations within `ext_localconf.php` instead of `ext_tables.php`, since the latter won't be available in the frontend anymore as soon as you logged out from the backend.